# Inspect x86 opcode bytes in LLVM Machine Function Pass

Tags: c++, x86, clang, llvm

I have a basic machine function pass in this fashion:

```
bool Foo::runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &Fn) {
  for (auto &BB : Fn) {
    for (MachineBasicBlock::iterator I = BB.begin(), E = BB.end(); I != E;
         ++I) {
      if (I->isPseudo())
        continue;
      // inspect opcode of I here
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Inside this loop I want to inspect the actual x86 opcodes (=array of bytes) for each instruction. `I->getOpcode()` only gives an integer which seems to be used internally by llvm.

I've been browsing through the llvm source code for an hour without finding a solution. I think I need to somehow lower `I` from `MachineInstr` to `MCInst` in order for that to be established. I've also seen `void X86MCCodeEmitter::EncodeInstruction(...)` which might be of use. However, llvm is a pretty complex beast and I did not manage to connect the dots.